# StackExchange.Redis issue in Azure Function (ResetNonConnected)

Tags: azure, redis, azure-functions, stackexchange.redis

I have an Azure Function called by a Logic App and the goal of this function is to read an Azure Redis Cache to find a particular key.
I use the StackExchange.Redis lib to read and write to the Redis cache.

The function can be called in parallel because multiple Logic App instances can be executed at the same time.
I have sometimes (but not rarely) a "ResetNonConnected" error while reading the content of the Redis Cache and when I start having this issue, I need to stop and start the Function App to make the function working again.

The code of my function is very simple: I read a key (StringGet), if it exists I compare it with a value I received as an input of my function. If the value received is greater than the one already in the cache of if the key is not in the cache, then I update the value in the cache (StringSet then KeyExpire).

Errors are not occurring during high load situation, I limited the number of instances of my Logic App to 10 in parallel, and I have this error.

Are there any known issues with this lib in an Azure function? What is the alternative to using a Redis Cache in an Azure function so to be sure that it will work just fine?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting some of the time values on the ConfigurationOptions?  This is when you Connect.

Comment: Not yet. I think that I found the root cause: my ConnectionMultiplexer variable is not declared statically so it means that I create a new connection each time I need to open a connection to the Redis cache. This is not the right way to proceed, so I'm going to fix it and then I will see if it works better.

Answer (score 0):

I won't help you with Redis error but

> What is the alternative to using a Redis Cache in an Azure function so to be sure that it will work just fine?

For read-key/write-key operations the typical approach would be to use Azure Table Storage. It has similar key-based API but it also has native support in Azure Functions in form of [Table Storage Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table). Most probably, you won't have to write any custom code to read/write values, but do everything directly with binding parameters.

Key lookups on Table Storage scale linearly to any load and cost almost nothing.

Comment: Ok, I see. I need to write my own purge to remove old data from the Table Storage because I don't think that there are eviction / expiration features, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of my issue: this was due to the fact that my ConnectionMultiplexer was not declared static and was created each time I called the function.
By declaring it as static, as well documented (my bad), it works just fine.